# How read a specific XmlNode without knowing its name

Tags: c#, text, xmlreader, xmlnode

couldn't find a specific answer to that

Here is an Xml example for my problem

```
<Rectangle>
    <elementcolor>blue</elementcolor>
    <elementwidth>200</elementwidth>
</Rectangle>
<Line>
    <elementcolor>red</elementcolor>
    <elementwidth>150</elementwidth>
</Line>
```

I want to get all the elements that have ChildNodes, and i don't want to get those who have simple text

I want to put into a list, in this example, Rectangle and Line.

But when asking .HasChildNodes to those nodes which contains simple text they return me True and as ChildNode[0].Name they return me "#text".

I can't simply asking .HasChildNodes, and i couldn't find other way to specify which node has a Node as ChildNode and which one has a "#text"

So i tried using XmlReader, this way:

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(file);
while (reader.Read())
{
    if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
    {
        list.Add(reader.Name);   
    }
}
```

This is returning me all Xml nodes, but i just want those who have a Node as ChildNode, how can i do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use linq2xml for that...

```
var xml = @"<wrapper>
<Rectangle>
    <elementcolor>blue</elementcolor>
    <elementwidth>200</elementwidth>
</Rectangle>
<Rectangle/>
<Line/>
<Line>
    <elementcolor>red</elementcolor>
    <elementwidth>150</elementwidth>
</Line>
</wrapper>";

var elements = XElement
    .Parse(xml)
    .Descendants()
    .Where(o => o.HasElements);
elements.Dump();
```

**OUTPUT**

```
<Rectangle>
  <elementcolor>blue</elementcolor>
  <elementwidth>200</elementwidth>
</Rectangle> 
<Line>
  <elementcolor>red</elementcolor>
  <elementwidth>150</elementwidth>
</Line>
```

Comment: Never heard about Linq before, just added the System.Xml.Linq reference to my project. But the .where query is not being reconized, is it something i'm missing?

Comment: most likely need to add a using System.Linq; as well as System.Xml.Linq;

Comment: elements.Dump() is a LinqPad thing. I use it all the time for my investigative work. http://www.linqpad.net/

Comment: Make sure you are referencing System.Core.dll in your project

Comment: added System.Linq and .where still not reconizable

Comment: Which .NET framework is your project targeting?  Needs to be greater than 2.0

Comment: I have V4 installed, have to go home now thanks so much for the help and for your time here, that helped me a lot i'll study more about Linq later. Thanks

Comment: oh i just finded out that my vs version suports only 2.0 framework, so this may not work for me, is there any way to achiev this without using Linq? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `XmlTextReader`. Use the new LINQ to XML API:

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load(file);
List<XElement> elementsWithChildren = document.Descendants()
                                              .Where(x => x.Elements().Any());
```

Comment: Never heard about Linq before, just added the System.Xml.Linq reference to my project. But the .where query is not being reconized, is it something i'm missing?

Comment: @Rafael You also need to add a using statement with System.Linq.